# google chrome auth box jumps around when using fb.login

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

when using simple example like at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

after auth box prompting for additional permissions appears, it jumps around the screen, and there is this message in the java console

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unsafe message can be ignored. It just happens before the cross domain loader code has initialized.

Never seen the chrome issue. Could you provide version numbers of browser and OS please?

Comment: Google chrome 17.0.963.46, on win2k3

Comment: oh, it happened when I enabled enhanced auth dialog, disabling it fixes issue.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll investigate